# Using variables to populate PHP arrays

Tags: php

For PHP, is it possible to do something like this:

```
array( $designationVar => $dataVar );
```

With the idea being that I can dynamically create an array based on the values present

Comment: that works :) good luck using it

Comment: @J0HN I've been using it, but some script it relies on isn't working. I decided to ask here for verification while trouble shooting the remainder of my code.

Comment: I'm just trying to say that if you just tried it in an isolated environment (like standalone script or interactive interpreter session) - it would be faster than asking. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes why not , this is equivalent to like this

```
$arr = array();

$arr[$keyname] = $value;
```

In your case

```
$arr = array();
$arr[$designationVar] = $dataVar;
```

Comment: See, that's what I figured, but it just doesn't want to work for some reason. Thanks for the confirmation though.